# Cant access a file from azure website

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

http://abcds.azurewebsites.net/scripts/abdsk.json

This file is available in the azure. But when i go to "http://abcds.azurewebsites.net/scripts/abdsk.json" i get a response back saying

GET http://abcds.azurewebsites.net/scripts/abdsk.json 404 (Not Found)

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Azure won't serve certain file types. You have to explicitly include the MIME type in order for Azure to serve the file.

In your Web App's web.config, add the following in the  section:

```
<staticContent>
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```